# Static Comments on Drupal Node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, comments, drupal-modules

I have a basic Drupal instance installed on my local server. One of the requirements I have is that users should be able to post comments on a node/article using static options given to them.

For e.g., if a user opens an article, in the comment section, rather then showing them free text option to comment, a set of fixed text strings is presented to them like, "Great Job", "This is a great post", "Bravo!", also a set of images like an image of a chocolate, image of flowers is shown. To leave a comment, user has to select either a string or an image for comments.

Is there any drupal module that provides this functionality, or any way I can do this (I have basic/beginner knowledge on how to create a module for Drupal).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by deleting `comment_body` field from **Comment fields** tab of content type & adding new field of type List(Text) with options of fixed text. Check screenshot below:

Step 1:
[image]

Step 2:
[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This fulfills the purpose! I can add img tags as options in comments too! Thanks a ton! :D

Comment: Doing this changes the comments overall on all nodes. Is there any way I can configure options for each node type? Like when creating a new article I should be able to specify what all options to show in comments.

Comment: You mean per node options variation?

Comment: Yes! While creating a new article I should be able to specify comment options to show in comments. E.g. node/1 (Article) should have option 1, option 2 and node/2 (Article) should have option 3 and option 4.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [Rate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rate) helps you.

This module provides flexible widgets for your node and comments. You have to create a `Custom` rate.

It has dependencies with Voting Api. If you have a basic level with Drupal I think you can do it. You only need to install this module and dependencies, and then create a Custom rate for some content type.